# How to use values from an appsettings.json file as href variables in an AMP html?

Tags: html, css, amp-html, amp-list, amp-mustache

I am programming an AMP website `www-dev.example.com` that points users to a sign-up page.

The sign up page is hosted on an identity server using the subdomain `auth.www-dev.example.com`.

I now want to deploy my AMP website to a staging environment `www-stg.example.com` and at the same time point users to it's respective staging identity server `auth.www-stg.example.com`.

Ideally I would have a config per environment in a relative `appsettings.json` file and use `amp-mustache` to map the environment variables into the the urls of `<button>` or `a` tags.

I'm currently achieving the desired functionality, somewhat, with `amp-list`, but it looks like a dogs breakfast causing some undesired and painstaking effects on the font end with alignment and scaling due to the fixed dimensions.

Is there a simple way to set environment variables in AMP for use in links?

HTML Implementation

```
<amp-list width="130" height="45" layout="flex-item" src="/appsettings.json">
 <template type="amp-mustache">
  <button type="button" on="tap:AMP.navigateTo(url='{{signup-url}}', target='_top')">Sign Up</button>
 </template>
</amp-list>
```

appsettings.json Implementation

```
{
    "items":[{
    "login-url":"https://auth.www-dev.example.com/login",
    "logout-url":"https://auth.www-dev.example.com/logout",
    "signup-url":"https://auth.www-dev.example.com/signup",
    "unsubscribe-url":"https://auth.www-dev.example.com/unsubscribe"
   }]
}
```

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated!

**Edit** - Example showing the start of the front end issues I'm looking to avoid

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ⚡ lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Bug</title>
    <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
    <script async custom-element="amp-list" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-list-0.1.js"></script>
    <script async custom-template="amp-mustache" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-mustache-0.2.js"></script>
    <link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com">
    <link
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap"
        rel="stylesheet">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style amp-custom>
        /* Delete this to reveal amp-list*/
        .flex {
            display: flex;
            flex-flow: row nowrap;
            justify-content: space-between;}

        .left {
            border: solid 1px blue;
        }
        .right {
            border:solid 1px green;
        }
    </style>
    <style amp-boilerplate>
        body {
            -webkit-animation: -amp-start 8s steps(1, end) 0s 1 normal both;
            -moz-animation: -amp-start 8s steps(1, end) 0s 1 normal both;
            -ms-animation: -amp-start 8s steps(1, end) 0s 1 normal both;
            animation: -amp-start 8s steps(1, end) 0s 1 normal both
        }

        @-webkit-keyframes -amp-start {
            from {
                visibility: hidden
            }

            to {
                visibility: visible
            }
        }

        @-moz-keyframes -amp-start {
            from {
                visibility: hidden
            }

            to {
                visibility: visible
            }
        }

        @-ms-keyframes -amp-start {
            from {
                visibility: hidden
            }

            to {
                visibility: visible
            }
        }

        @-o-keyframes -amp-start {
            from {
                visibility: hidden
            }

            to {
                visibility: visible
            }
        }

        @keyframes -amp-start {
            from {
                visibility: hidden
            }

            to {
                visibility: visible
            }
        }
    </style><noscript>
        <style amp-boilerplate>
            body {
                -webkit-animation: none;
                -moz-animation: none;
                -ms-animation: none;
                animation: none
            }
        </style>
    </noscript>
    <template id="foo" type="amp-mustache">
        <button class="button-secondary" type="button"
            on="tap:AMP.navigateTo(url='{{signup-url}}', target='_top')">Sign Up</button>
    </template>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="flex">
        <div class="left">
            <p>Flex Left</p>
            <button on="tap:foobar.changeToLayoutContainer()">Change Layout</button>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <amp-list id="foobar" width="auto" height="1" src="/appsettings.json" template="foo">
                <div placeholder>Loading</div>
                <div fallback>Failed to load data.</div>
            </amp-list>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Put `amp-list` before `</body>`.  Assign template ID to `<amp-list>` and `<tempate>`, Set `width="auto" height="1">`

Comment: Thanks for your note, the button appears successfully at the bottom of the page. The front end issues surface when when I use amp-list and the parent style is `display: flex; flex-flow: row nowrap; justify-content: space-between;` it seems like the flex box does not resize after the content loads.

Comment: the above note only works if you separate list and template. if template is a child of list, you have to size it correctly. if you separate the two and put list as a child of body before the body close, sizing/resizing will work correctly even when height=1.

Comment: I've separated the two but the issue persists when I introduce a flex container. Interestingly If I introduce the user trigger`<button on="tap:amp-listID.changeToLayoutContainer()">Resize</button>` at the top of the body then my desired layout appears when clicked.

Comment: interesting! IME the separation of list and template, linked via ID, handles all desktop sizing issues (a lesson learned from sebastian benz at AMP). however have never used template as child of a flex container. the benz solution is, in effect, flexible on load. caveat: we too have to use overlfow + show-more on mobile. the benz solution works well on desktop but not mobile.

Comment: I ended up doing away with amp-list and parsing the html through the deployment engine as a template, in my case it was terraform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Terraform and parsing the html file through as a template during deployment, prior to uploading the html to its hosting destination.

HCL

```
module "template_files" {
  source               = "hashicorp/dir/template"
  base_dir             = "./src/static_website"
  template_file_suffix = ".html"
  
  template_vars = {
    canonical  = var.canonical
    signup-url = var.signup-url
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<button type="button" on="tap:AMP.navigateTo(url='${signup-url}', target='_top')">Sign Up</button>
```